# Numercial simulation of the double slit experiment

Tags: computational-physics, double-slit-experiment, interference, diffraction

Originally I had a code that simulates single slit diffraction:

parameters for functions: `f(start_of_a_slit, end_of_a_slit, start_of_a_screen, end_of_a_screen, number_of_points, distance_between_screen_and_slit, wavenumber, amplitude)`

```
    double k = 2.0 * M_PI / lambda;
    double complexAmp[numPnt + 1];

    Real fReal(-a / 2.0, a / 2.0, c, d, numPnt, dDif, k, amp);
    Imaginary fIm(-a / 2.0, a / 2.0, c, d, numPnt, dDif, k, amp);
    // integration
    std::ofstream file("wave.bin");
    for (int i = 1; i <= numPnt; i++) {
        fReal.simpson(-a / 2.0, a / 2.0, fReal.y[i], dDif, k, amp, numInt);
        fIm.simpson(-a / 2.0, a / 2.0, fIm.y[i], dDif, k, amp, numInt);
        complexAmp[i] = fReal.integral * fReal.integral +
                fIm.integral * fIm.integral;
        file << fReal.y[i] << "\t" << complexAmp[i] << std::endl;
    }
```

Where method simpson calculates the integral of a function:

```
double Real::value (double x, double y, double d, double k, double amp) {
    double r = sqrt(d * d + (y - x) * (y - x));
    return amp * cos(k * r) / sqrt(r);
}

void Real::simpson(double a, double b, double y, double d, double k, double amp, double size) {
    double h = (b - a) / (2.0 * (double)(size));
    double simpson = .0;
    double x = a + h;
    int i = 1;
    while (i < size + 1) {
        simpson = simpson + (value(x + h, y, d, k, amp) +
                4.0 * value(x, y, d, k, amp) + value(x - h, y, d, k, amp))
                        *  h / 3.0;
        x = x + 2.0 * h;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    integral = simpson;
}
```

Now I want to change the program so that it simulates double-slit diffraction and I don't know how to do this. I need to create another set of functions, with a slit shifted by some distance. But how do I calculate the integral: do I need to add the values of the functions from two different slits first or do I integrate them first, and then add them together and raise them to the power of two to calculate the intensity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume that the light has a sufficiently large coherence length, you have to calculate the amplitude of each slit on the detector, $A_1$ and $A_2$. Next, since most detectors measure the intensity, the quantity to calculate is proportional to $|A_1 + A_2|^2$.